# Hardcoding my value in rspec is not working

Tags: ruby, rspec

My following class is like so:

```
    attr_reader :player, :player_choice, :cpu_choice, :choices, :game, :result

    def initialize(player)
        @player = player
        @player_choice = ""
        @cpu_choice = ""
        @choices = Choices.new
        @result = ""
    end

def get_result
        @result
end

def show_cpu_choice
        @cpu_choice
    end

 def set_player_choice(choice)
        @player_choice = choice
        set_cpu_choice
        decide_winner
    end

def set_cpu_choice
        @cpu_choice = @choices.get_choices.sample
    end
```

I have omitted any irrelevant methods but basically I want to hardcode my @cpu_choice to "Scissors" for example so this following test can work,since my cpu choice is randomly generated but it is not working whichever method i am trying in rspec.
My set_cpu_choice randomonises from an array from an instance variable in my Choices class btw.

```
let(:game) {Game.new("Johnny")}

describe 'Player wins' do
        it 'Player selects Rock and CPU has picked Scissors' do
            game.set_player_choice("Rock")
            allow(game).to receive(:show_cpu_choice).and_return("Scissors")
            expect(game.get_result).to eq("Johnny")
        end     
    end
```

I have tried the above in my rspec and I have also tried to do it using instance_variable_set but my test still keeps randomising the cpu choice.

I have also looked at something called srand but that looks too complicated for me since I dont understand any of it.

Comment: Not sure how the other methods look, but stubbing a method that returns `@cpu_choice` will not help if the other methods are using `@cpu_choice` directly.

Answer (score 0):

So I'll assume that `decide_winner` calls `show_cpu_choice` and sets `@result`. The problem is that when set_player_choice is called `game` hasn't yet been set up to return "Scissors". The `allow` should be moved before the call to `set_player_choice`